# python fastest way to match strings with huge data size

Tags: python, numpy, astropy

I have a huge table data (or record array) with elements:

```
tbdata[i]['a'], tbdata[i]['b'], tbdata[i]['c']
```

which are all integers, and `i` is a random number between 0 and  1 million (the size of the table).

I also have a list called `Name` whose elements are all names (900 names in total) of files, such as `'/Users/Desktop/Data/spe-3588-55184-0228.jpg'` (modified), all containing three numbers.

Now I want to select those data from my `tbdata` whose elements mentioned above all match the three numbers in the names of list `Name`. Here's the code I originally wrote:

```
Data = []
for k in range(0, len(tbdata)):
    for i in range(0, len(NameA5)):
        if Name[i][43:47] == str(tbdata[k]['a']) and\
             Name[i][48:53] == str(tbdata[k]['b']) and\
             Name[i][55:58] == str(tbdata[k]['c']):
            Data.append(tbdata[k])
```

Python ran for the whole night and still haven't finished, since either the size of data is huge or my algorithm is too slow...I'm wondering what's the fastest way to complete such a task? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using python lists? Have you tried using Pandas for your problem?

Comment: A few obvious things, although I couldn't say how much difference it would make.  Unless you are using Python 3, then `xrange()` is preferred over `range()`. But consider iterating through the lists instead of using indexes.    You are creating strings from `tbdata[k]['a'] and ['b']  `len(NameA5)` times, just create them as temporary variables in the outer loop.

Comment: Just noticed that your inner loop is using `len(NameA5)` but you are indexing `Name`.  Typos in the question or a mistake?

Comment: What is the task you're actually trying to accomplish? It's fine to explain what you tried but what is the data you're using and what are you trying to do with it? There's probably a better way especially if you have Numpy arrays. Also why is this tagged astropy? Is something you're trying to do with astronomy data?

Comment: @cdarke Oops yes it is a typo here. I indeed tried iterating with `xrange` for a small portion of data but the difference in time was somewhat negligible...

Comment: @BudoZindovic  Hum..I will check it out!
@lguananaut   Yes these are all astronomy data. `tbdata` is the original huge fits data for many objects, and `Name` comes from reading the names of individual spectrum (the spectrums of objects in `tbdata`) fits files. I want to select those objects from tbdata which has the same 'plate', 'mjd' and 'fiberid' (basically the same objects) as the individual spectrums to do further inspection.

Comment: [Pandas dataframes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe) or [astropy's data table](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/index.html) can probably do what you want. Note that with the recent astropy 1.1 release, you can convert between them if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a lookup tree like this:

```
a2b2c = {}
for name in NameA5:
    a = int(name[43:47])
    b = int(name[48:53])
    c = int(name[55:58])

    if a not in a2b2c2name:
        a2b2c2name[a] = {}
    if b not in a2b2c2name[a]:
        a2b2c2name[a][b] = {}
    a2b2c2name[a][b][c] = True

for k in range(len(tbdata)):
    a = tbdata[k]['a']
    b = tbdata[k]['b']
    c = tbdata[k]['c']
    if a in a2b2c2name and b in a2b2c2name[a] and c in a2b2c2name[a][b]:
        Data.append(tbdata[k])
```

Comment: FYI, the two checks and sets and the final set can be simplified to: `a2b2c2name.setdefault(a, {}).setdefault(b, {})[c] = True`

Comment: Wow looks like an interesting method! Thanks a lot!